# Python: Creating a function that compares 2 arrays and inserts the larger elements between the 2 arrays

Tags: python, arrays, list, function, insert

I am trying to create a function that compares 2 arrays and creates a new list with the maximum elements of the list without using numpy. I managed to create a manual version, but am having issues implementing this into a function.

Task: Create a function maximum_arrays(a,b) that compares both arrays a and b element-wise and returns a new array containing the larger elements. Use the insert2 function to add new elements to a list.

Example: from applying the function to the arrays a=[12,5,8,19,6] and b=[3,6,2,12,4] the result should be c=[12,6,8,19,6].

Current Code:

```
list_a = [12,5,8,19,6]
list_b = [3,6,2,12,4]

maximum_arrays = []
for item in list_a:
    if list_b[item] > list_a[item]:
        maximum_arrays.insert(list_b[item])
    else:
        maximum_arrays.insert(list_a[item])

print(maximum_arrays)
```

Manual Version:

```
list_a = [12,5,8,19,6]
list_b = [3,6,2,12,4]
#answer example
c = [12,6,8,19,6]

#empty list
maximum_arrays = []

#for each part of the list, choose the highest number of the other list and insert
maximum_arrays.insert(0, max(list_a[0],list_b[0]))
maximum_arrays.insert(1, max(list_a[1],list_b[1]))
maximum_arrays.insert(2, max(list_a[2],list_b[2]))
maximum_arrays.insert(3, max(list_a[3],list_b[3]))
maximum_arrays.insert(4, max(list_a[4],list_b[4]))

print(maximum_arrays)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this :

```
list_a = [12,5,8,19,6]
list_b = [3,6,2,12,4]

l = []
for i,j in enumerate(zip(list_a, list_b)):
    l.insert(i, max(j))

print(l)
```

Answer (score 1):

use `max` in a list comprehension over the zipped lists, or `numpy.max`.

```py
list_a = [12,5,8,19,6]
list_b = [3,6,2,12,4]

max_array = [max(i) for i in zip(list_a, list_b)]

print(max_array)
```

The explanation here is: `zip` turns n iterables into an iterator over tuples, where each tuple has `n` items. So, in the two-list case, `zip([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6])` turns into `((1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6))`. Taking the `max` of all of these tuples gives you your list.

An important caveat, and one that has burned me several times, is that the number of tuples generated is the length of the *shortest* iterable in the `zip`. In other words, `zip` does not throw an exception when passed iterables of different lengths, and just stops when one of the input lists runs out. In this respect it differs from `numpy.max`, which does throw an error when given lists of different lengths.

Answer (score 0):

Other way using [`itertools.starmap`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.starmap):

```
list(starmap(max, zip(list_a, list_b)))
```

Output:

```
[12, 6, 8, 19, 6]
```

This is about 1.4x faster than list comprehension:

```
%timeit list(starmap(max, zip(list_a, list_b)))
# 1.19 µs ± 49.3 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

%timeit [max(i) for i in zip(list_a, list_b)]
# 1.69 µs ± 213 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve many ways , Same as your function or list comprehension using zip function. 
Below solution on your way, If both length is same then take one list length and iterate and use the "append"/"insert" option to add the value to list.

```
list_a = [12,5,8,19,6]
list_b = [3,6,2,12,4]

maximum_arrays = []
list_length = len(list_a)
for item in range(list_length):
if list_b[item] > list_a[item]:
    maximum_arrays.append(list_b[item])
else:
    maximum_arrays.append(list_a[item])

print(maximum_arrays)
```